# Cast insensitive regex group

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this: `[0-9a-z]`

which matches a character that's a number or lowercase letter. If I wanted to match all alphanumerics I could do: `[0-9a-zA-Z]`, but I am simply wondering if there is shorthand to match all alphanumerics?

Comment: Use the `/i/` modifier in your pattern.

Comment: i couldn't use `/i` for the whole regex, just for the groups

Comment: There is no way to make a fragment of a pattern lowercase, only the entire pattern.

Comment: Many flavors of regex have special character classes like `[[:alnum:]]` which does exactly what you're asking for, but this isn't available in javascript's regex. However. there's the "word" character class `\w`, which matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. If false positives on underscores aren't a concern, this is what you're looking for.

Comment: yeah I don't want to match underscores, but thanks I might be able to use that